# iPhone 5 not showing in Compatibility on App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I recently updated my application. Uploaded from **xCode 8.1** with minimum deployment target **8.1**. As the new version went live the iPhone 5 device was removed from the compatibility matrix. Any idea why the support was removed for iPhone 5(tried on iPhone 5 with OS 10.1.1.)

Even when i try to run from xCode on a iPhone 5 then i am getting the message

**"This iPhone 5(Model A1429)is running iOS 10.1.1(14B100), which may not be supported by this version of xCode"**

Comment: Have you added the 3.5, 4, 4.7 and 5.5 Inch Display screenshot over iTune Connect?

Comment: @maddy yes i have

Answer (score 0):

**There is a new Xcode version available** through the Mac App store. **Try to update it.**

**You can also download the beta version** if you want to get earlier features that is exactly 4GB.

Let me know if you experience this error **again.**

Comment: can i update a build to app store with xcode beta version?